# Generate random coordinates, store within circle radius

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a formula that generates numbers that need to be displayed on a grid. All points should start expanding from origin, equally to all sides.

These should expand randomly to all sides, however, because formula is changing with time, there are more and more points to display.

Let's say we have 100 points and we've set them on grid, formula updates and we have 150 points. Graph should only update with 50 new ones.

Is there any way to do this in React JavaScript?

Below is a trial in Java that does not store numbers, just visualises.

```
public void getRandomPointInCircle() {
    double t = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random();
    double r = Math.sqrt(Math.random());
    double x = r * Math.cos(t);
    double y = r * Math.sin(t);
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y);
}
```

[Circle - Trial 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfFoe.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. There's nothing particularly React-specific here, the math is the same and JS has all of the things used by that Java code to do this...

Comment: You may be trying to reinvent the wheel, please check out google maps api or mapbox api.. And it’s open source code on github..

Comment: Sorry, not doing with google maps api.. canva?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking here is having a stateful component (React is good at handling that). This component can store the number of points and each one of the positions, each time you add a new point, you will call the set state Method with the new State, which will be the previous one plus the new points.

```
class Circle extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {points : [], npoints : 0}
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="circle">... implement this render view ...
        <Points data={this.state.points}></Points>
      </div>
    );
  }

  addNewPoints(){
    let newPoints = [...this.state.points];
    newPoints.push(this.generateNewPoints());
    newState = {points :newPoints , npoints : newPoints.length}
    this.setState(newState);
  } 

  generateNewPoints(){
    //getRandomPointInCircle ...
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

React may be particularly well suited for this task. Run the snippet below to see it work.

The trick to make sure react only renders the new elements is the use of a unique `key` prop on each rendered circle. Unchanged keys don't get re-rendered.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      points: []
    };
  }

  getRandomPointInCircle() {
    const t = 2 * Math.PI * Math.random();
    const r = Math.sqrt(Math.random());
    const cx = r * Math.cos(t);
    const cy = r * Math.sin(t);
    const fill = '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
    return {cx, cy, fill, r:"0.02"};
  }
  addPoints = () => {
    const points = this.state.points.concat(
      new Array(20).fill().map(p => this.getRandomPointInCircle())
    );
    this.setState({points})
  }

  render() {
    const {points} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
      <button onClick={this.addPoints}>Add 20 points</button><br/>
        <svg style={{overflow:'visible'}} height="200px" viewBox="-1 -1 2 2">
          <rect width="2" height="2" x="-1" y="-1" fill="#efefef" />
          <circle cx={0} cy={0}r={1} fill="#ffffff" />
          {points.map((p,index)=>(
            <circle
              key={`${p.x}-${p.y}-${index}`}
              {...p}
            />
          ))}
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Great code! I tried writing something similar, however, is there any way to make them form first in the centre, and then spread across the whole circle? In this example the dots are scattered across the entire space... which is not something I am looking for

Comment: @Johnny sure, by storing and increasing the diameter used in the `getRandomPointInCircle` function (2)

Comment: Okay, so we basically create another formula to manipulate the radius; saying - time2 = radius (random max 5) .. time5 = radius (random up to 20)?